# Angular 11 Router data observable not updated when data has not changed

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, subscribe

I have this Angular resolver:

```js
@Injectable()
export class DataResolver implements Resolve<any> {

    constructor(private apiService: ApiService) {}
    
    public resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): any {
      const data = {
        param1: route.queryParamMap.get('param1'),
        param2: route.queryParamMap.get('param2'),
      };
      return this.apiService.search(data);
    }
}
```

The apiService.search method looks like this:

```js
public search(data): Observable<any> {
  let params = new HttpParams(); 
  for (const key in data) {
    if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      const value = data[key];
      if (value) {
        params = params.set(key, value);
      }
    }
  }

  return this.http.get<any>(`${API_URL}/endpoint`, { params });
}
```

Then I have a component that subscribes to changes on the `ActivatedRoute`'s data:

```js
route.data.subscribe((data) => {
  console.log(data);
});
```

And the route looks like this:

```
{
  component: HomeComponent,
  path: '/',
  resolve: {
    data: DataResolver,
  },
  runGuardsAndResolvers: 'paramsOrQueryParamsChange',
}
```

The problem is, the subscription handler only gets called if the `data` actually changes, regardless of if the `resolve` method of the resolver has been called. In particular, if two (or more) subsequent resolve calls resolve an empty array then the line `console.log(data)` only gets called the first time.

Is this the expected behaviour? can I force the observable to emit a new value?

My goal is to show a message every time the resolve resolves an empty array, regardless of if it was empty before.

Comment: Can you please describe what you are trying to atcheive regardless of your implementation? You'd like to show a message every time you get data from the server? how does the route change effects that?

Comment: @noamsteiner Yes, like I said, I want to display a message every time the response from the server is an empty array, the way this relates to route changes is the following:
When a user performs a new search they get redirected to a URL with the search parameters as query params, so the resolve method actually gets those params from the URL and then sends the request to the server (I'd removed this from the code sample for brevity, I'll add it back)

Comment: Where in your code you are calling the `resolve` method? Also if you could please add the `search` method code it would be helpful.

Comment: @noamsteiner I'm not calling the `resolve` method, Angular calls it every time a specific route is loaded, I've confirmed that the resolve method does indeed get called, is just the subscription handler that doesn't. I've added the requested code, including the whole resolver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have unnecessarily wrapped the observable in a promise and resolved it. Try rewriting your resolver like this.

```js
@Injectable()
export class DataResolver implements Resolve<any> {
    constructor(private apiService: ApiService) {}

    public resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): any {
        const data = {
            param1: route.queryParamMap.get("param1"),
            param2: route.queryParamMap.get("param2"),
        };

        return this.apiService.search(data);
    }
}
```

I would also look at cleaning up your API service by using HttpPrams

```js
// import { HttpClient,HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
public search(data): Observable<any> {
  let params = new HttpParams({ fromObject: data });
  return this.http.get<any>(`${API_URL}/endpoint`, { params });
}
```

you may need to add the resolver to your route table

```js
RouterModule.forRoot([{
  path: 'yourRoute',
  component: YourComponent,
  resolve: {
    yourDataWillBeInThisProperty: DataResolver
  }
}])
```

if you want the component to reload you may need to change the `onSameUrlNavigation` property in your router module

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload' }) ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

I would not recommend using the `onSameUrlNavigation` for your issue but would just subscribe to the `route.queryParams` observable and trigger the search there.

In your component

```js
ngOnInit(){
  this.sub = this.route.queryParams.subscribe(() => { this.data = this.route.snapshot.data.data; }); 
  // don't forget to unSubscribe
}
```

Comment: Thank you! that cleans up my code a bit, but it does not solve my problem.

Comment: what do you have in your route table?

Comment: added the route code to the question.
Again, the resolver works fine, the thing is, I'm subscribed to its data stream and that stream only seems to be emitting values if the data changes, I need to know every time the resolver gets called.

Comment: the resolver is called by the router. It is called each time you navigate to the `/` route. What do you have in the code for router navigation?

Comment: I would not recommend using the `onSameUrlNavigation` for your issue but would just subscribe to the `route.queryParams` observable and trigger the search there.

Comment: That did it! using the route.queryParams observable I managed to do this:

this.route.queryParams.subscribe(() => {
    this.data = this.route.snapshot.data.data;
});

If you want to edit your answer I'll select it as a solution